# CSS Transitions Not Working After jQuery Animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Okay, so I've got three divs in the form of bubbles. Right now I'm just working on the first one. They're supposed to explode when clicked, taking up almost all of the screen, and then come back down to the original bubble when the title is clicked. Here's the code - this whole thing will be much easier to explain if you run it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>KURB - Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kurb.css"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <p id="k">KURB</p>
        </div>
        <div id="about">
            <p class="label">Blah blah blah</p>
        </div>
        <div id="work">
            <p class="label">Blah blah blah</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact">
            <p class="label">Blah blah blah</p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var main = $("#main");
            var about = $("#about");
            var work = $("#work");
            var contact = $("#contact");

            var open = false;

            about.click(function() {
                about.animate({
                    height: "100vh",
                    marginTop: "0vh",
                    width: "100%",
                    marginLeft: "0%",
                    borderRadius: "0",
                    opacity: "1"
                }, 300);

                main.animate({
                    marginTop: "1vh"
                }, 300);

                about.css("cursor", "auto");
                work.css("display", "none");
                contact.css("display", "none");
                main.css("cursor", "pointer");

                open=true;
            });

            main.click(function() {
                if (open = true) {
                    work.css("display", "inline");
                    contact.css("display", "inline");
                    main.css("cursor", "auto");

                    about.animate({
                        width: "38%",
                        marginLeft: "31%",
                        height: "30vh",
                        marginTop: "7vh",
                        borderRadius: "100%",
                        opacity: "0.6"
                    }, 300);

                    main.animate({
                        marginTop: "10vh"
                    }, 300);

                    about.css("cursor", "pointer");

                    open=false;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 10vh;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    margin-left: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}

#k {
    font-family: Questrial;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    color: #404040;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #404040;
    line-height: 0.85;
}

#about {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 38%;
    height: 30vh;
    margin-top: 7vh;
    margin-left: 31%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #33CC33;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity .5s, margin-top .5s, margin-bottom .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, margin-top .5s, margin-bottom .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#about:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

#work {
    float: left;
    width: 38%;
    height: 30vh;
    margin-top: 0vh;
    margin-left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #323280;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity .5s, margin-top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, margin-top .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#work:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: -2vh;
}

#contact {
    float: right;
    width: 38%;
    height: 30vh;
    margin-top: 0vh;
    margin-right: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FF6600;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity .5s, margin-top .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, margin-top .5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#contact:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: -2vh;
}

.label {
    font-family: Questrial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Now I've been able to do all this. The problem is, afterwards, the CSS transition that's supposed to change the opacity and margin-top/margin-bottom doesn't seem to work. The opacity doesn't change at all and the div doesn't move up - the bottom two divs move down. I have no idea why, but I suspect it's because I'm screwing it up with the jQuery animations somehow. I've noticed that when the div is full sized, the CSS transitions are deactivated. Maybe they stay deactivated? ... Help?

Comment: In your `main.click()` function you have an error with the if condition statement. It should be `if (open === true) {` if being compared to true. It doesn't solve your problem but I hope it helps debugging :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
transition: opacity .5s, margin-top .5s !important;
```

put the `!important` keyword at the end of your styling properties and it should work after you do any jQuery related stuff

I would also advise you to make a function that does any common functionality between the two click events. Add some arguments (like the element to animate, and the animation parameters) and use those to supply the animation info:

```
func animateElement(elementToAnimate, height, width //etc {

 elementToAnimate.animate({
                    height: height,
                    marginTop: "0vh",
                    width: width,
                    marginLeft: "0%",
                    borderRadius: "0",
                    opacity: "1"
                }, 300);

}
```

Comment: That worked. The problem now is when the div is full-sized, it'll move if you mouse out. Are there any solutions to this, or am I going to have to remove the :hover CSS with jQuery? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Tommay hmm, give me a second to look and think

Comment: Perhaps the answer is to make a whole different id with the same characteristics as the original id except without the :hover thing? Seems like that would get very annoying though...

Comment: @Tommay I've moved your code to this fiddle. What do you mean it'll move if you mouse out? I don't see any movement when I mouse out http://jsfiddle.net/m3su2g3g/

Comment: If you add our !important solution it does.

Comment: @Tommay why don't you open my fiddle, update the code, save the fiddle, and link the new fiddle down here so I can see. Mine doesn't seem to be doing anything after clicking (it just expands)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83924/discussion-between-abdul-ahmad-and-tommay).